# Why is my PowerShell undefined when run npm run dev?

Tags: windows, powershell, npm

I'm using Windows 11 and I have a Vue project that uses Vite. If I use PowerShell to run "npm run dev" (which is vite --open --host), I am met with this error:[image]

I can see that the path is 'undefined\System32...', but when I check the environment variables and Windows Terminal settings, everything seems fine.
[image]

[image]

I already have %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 in my User variables list.
I also try to replace %SystemRoot% with C:\Windows, but it still doesn't work.
I tried this solution but it doesn't work:
[Error when trying to rum npm start command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547473/error-when-trying-to-rum-npm-start-command)

I'm using node v16.15.1
My project runs fine if I use bash shell.
How should I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the code you use to spawn the powershell?

Comment: @Mureinik I don't use any code. I just open power shell, cd to my project folder and "npm run dev"

Comment: Sounds like npm doesn't know what %systemroot% is.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the BROWSER env variable is set in your .env file. I encountered the same issue when I accidentally removed BROWSER='none' from .env